# Checkbox is not working properly with React state

Tags: reactjs, input, checkbox, react-state

I am building a form where the hotel owners will add a hotel and select a few amenities of the same hotel. The problem is If I use state in the onChange function the checkbox tick is not displayed. I don't know where I made a mistake?

```
import React from "react";
import { nanoid } from "nanoid";

const ListAmenities = ({
  amenities,
  className,
  setHotelAmenities,
  hotelAmenities,
}) => {
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const inputValue = e.target.dataset.amenitieName;
    if (hotelAmenities.includes(inputValue) === true) {
      const updatedAmenities = hotelAmenities.filter(
        (amenitie) => amenitie !== inputValue
      );
      setHotelAmenities(updatedAmenities);
    } else {
      //If I remove this second setState then everything works perfectly.
      setHotelAmenities((prevAmenities) => {
        return [...prevAmenities, inputValue];
      });
    }
  };

  return amenities.map((item) => {
    return (
      <div className={className} key={nanoid()}>
        <input
          onChange={handleChange}
          className="mr-2"
          type="checkbox"
          name={item}
          id={item}
          data-amenitie-name={item}
        />
        <label htmlFor={item}>{item}</label>
      </div>
    );
  });
};

export default ListAmenities;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `key={nanoid()}`. Instead, using `key={item]` should solve your probem.

I believe your application that uses ListAmenities is something like this:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [hotelAmenities, setHotelAmenities] = useState([]);
  return (
    <ListAmenities
      amenities={["A", "B", "C"]}
      className="test"
      setHotelAmenities={setHotelAmenities}
      hotelAmenities={hotelAmenities}
    />
  );
};
```

In your current implementation, when `handleChange` calls `setHotelAmenities` it changed `hotelAmenities` which is a prop of `ListAmenities` and causes the `ListAmenities` to rerender. Since you use `key={nanoid()}` react assumes that a new item has been added and the old one has been removed. So it re-renders the checkbox. Since there is no default value of checkbox, it is assumed that it is in unchecked state when it is re-rendered.

Comment: Yes, You're Right! Thank you for the clear explanation!